# "Doesn't have required permission to access the domain" when trying to connect to domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to build a web application for our organization which will utilize our O365 for the authentication. while trying to connect to the domain using the Administrator account, I ran into this error which mentioned that the admin..onmicrosoft.com(Global Administrator), doesnt have the required permission to access the domain.

[image]

I've also tried assigning my own ID with the global administrator but the same error appears.

Anyone here mind to guide me to the correct path ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve the problem using VS2017 community version and Azure free version: "Domain:" should fill itself out automatically and should not be changed. If it didn't fill itself automatically go to "File/Account Settings" on VS 2017 and click on "Check for an updated license". Then re-start a new project. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check whether the account is the admin of the tenant you were developing. You can sign-in the [portal](http://portal.azure.com) and switch to the target tenant and check it by navigate to the user like figure below:
[image]

Or another solution is that, you can register the app on the Azure portal then click the **More Options** and enable **Overwrite the application entry if one with same id exits** like figure below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you feixue for the reply. I'm sure that the account is the admin account. [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/Rqhuk). i've also tried the [alternative method](http://imgur.com/a/4MwoG) but it gave the same error as well. I've entered both Application ID & Object ID but it still show the 'required access' warning.

Comment: Did you sign-in Visual Studio with multiple accounts? Or can you reproduce the issue on other machine? Also as a workaround, you can refer the code sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) to developing with Azure AD.